# State values given bidiagonal transition matrix in a Markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a problem which I "simplified" into a simple Markov chain with a constant transition matrix.
The transition matrix is a bidiagonal matrix looking like :
\begin{align}
P = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1-\alpha & 2\alpha & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & 1-2\alpha & 3\alpha & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \max(0,1-(k-1)\alpha) & \min(1,k\alpha)
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
Now I have an initial state $p_0$ defined as $\{1,0,0,\ldots,0\}$.

**My objective is to have the values of $P^np_0$** (so the state after $n$ steps in the chain) or at least an **approximation/bound on them**.

I thought the bidiagonal form would help but there is unfortunately not much documentation on it.

Comment: Are the min and max conditions applied to your top left values as well ? The pattern not being the same at the top-left and at the bottom-right leads to ambiguity.

Comment: They are indeed the same but one can solve the problem by truncating the matrix appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $P$ and its transpose $P^T$ are the same, and $P^T$ is upper-diagonal. The diagonal entries $\min(1,i\alpha)$ are therefore the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $P$. You can write 
$$P = U \Lambda U^{-1},$$
where $\Lambda = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k)$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, and $U$ is the matrix whose $i^{th}$ column is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$. Then 
$$P^n = U \Lambda^n U^{-1}.$$
It remains only to compute $U$, which I leave to you. Your answer will be left-multiplication by the row vector $p_0^T$ (you have written it as right-multiplication, but called it the "initial state" -- one of these is wrong).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had this intuition as well, but there I could not find a nice analytical solution for $U$, especially since the inverse can make things nasty...

Comment: @ThéoGaly-Fajou It should not be hard to approximate $U$ well enough to get an estimate on $p_0^T P^n$ (assuming again that you are working with the transition matrix $P$, an issue you have not corrected). Also, observe that $P^T$ is upper-triangular and you know its eigenvalues are $\min(1,i\alpha)^n$. Note that the column vector $(1,0,...,0)^T$ is an eigenvector of $(P^T)^n$ with eigenvalue $\alpha^n$, hence $(P^T)^n p_0 = \alpha^n p_0$.